# GRAILS - web service client using client certificate

Tags: java, web-services, grails, ssl

I am trying to write a Web Service test and it needs to connect to a Web Service using a client certificate. I have already set up a server that accepts client certificates and it works correctly when using a .NET client application.
The client certificate works as an authentication mechanism together with spring security plugin, therefore i need a way to write a client that can use my custom certificate when performing a request.

Now i am trying to write an integration test for testing this service but i cannot find any mean to attach client certificate when performing a request. I have thried wsclient for groovy, ws-lite for groovy and even cxf for java. Still no luck.

Is there any way that i can attach my own, custom client certificate to web service client request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HttpBuilder, specifically look here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/AuthConfig.html

Comment: Nice to know there is at least SOME way. Is there a way to use httpbuilder in some other web services client? Or do i have to manually parse XMLs in order to test a web service?

Comment: HttpBuilder automatically parses XML as long as you specify the contentType as XML. Same with JSON. Look at the examples on their site. It's fantastic.

Comment: Better this than nothing then, i was hoping there is some way to attach certificates to web service connections using cxf or some other library. I guess i would have to do it the hard way :)

Comment: You can with HttpBuilder. You have access to underlying java httpclient where you can do just about anything.